# Finding the minimum value of a nested object property

Tags: javascript, object, reduce

I have an object that looks like this:

```
const yo = {
  one: {
    value: 0,
    mission: 17},
  two: {
    value: 18,
    mission: 3},
  three: {
    value: -2,
    mission: 4},
}
```

I want to find the minimum value of the `mission` prop within the nested objects. This line works to find the minimum value of the nested `value` prop and returns `-2`:

```
const total = Object.values(yo).reduce((t, {value}) => Math.min(t, value), 0)
```

But when I try the same thing for the `mission` prop, it returns `0` when it should be `3`:

```
const total = Object.values(yo).reduce((t, {mission}) => Math.min(t, mission), 0)
```

Is there something that I am missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `0` as the initial value of accumulator i.e `t`. `0` is less than all the `mission` values. So you need to pass the greatest value i.e `Infinity` as second argument of `reduce()`.

```js
const yo = {
  one: {
    value: 0,
    mission: 17},
  two: {
    value: 18,
    mission: 3},
  three: {
    value: -2,
    mission: 4},
}
const total = Object.values(yo).reduce((t, {mission}) => Math.min(t, mission), Infinity);
console.log(total)
```

Comment: @KontrolEgo Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with it

Answer (score 4):

In this case, `map` is enough.

```js
const yo = {
  one: {
    value: 9,
    mission: 17
  },
  two: {
    value: 18,
    mission: 6
  },
  three: {
    value: 3,
    mission: 4
  },
}

const total = Object.values(yo).map(({ mission }) => mission);
console.log(Math.min(...total));
```

Comment: @Tigran: Pretty nice :)