# Get Minimum Value From Array of Objects from JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

This is my *data.json* file... **And i want minimum cost if arrival is Amsterdam and departure is London**

Can someone tell me how to map through it

```
{
"currency":"EUR",
 "deals": [{"departure":"London",
           "arrival":"Amsterdam",
           "cost":160,"transport":"train"},
          {"departure":"London",
           "arrival":"Amsterdam",
           "cost":40,"transport":"car"},
          {"departure":"London",
           "arrival":"Amsterdam",
           "cost":120,"transport":"bus"}]
}
```

I tried:

```
const x = data.deals.map((v)=>{
  if(v.departure==="London" && v.arrival==="Amsterdam"){ 
    return v.cost
  }
}
```

Comment: yes--     const x=data.deals.map((v)=>{if(v.departure==="London" && v.arrival==="Amsterdam"){ return v.cost
}
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the minimum value of a nested object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64962678/finding-the-minimum-value-of-a-nested-object-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = {
  "currency": "EUR",
  "deals": [{
      "departure": "London",
      "arrival": "Amsterdam",
      "cost": 160,
      "transport": "train"
    },
    {
      "departure": "London",
      "arrival": "Amsterdam",
      "cost": 40,
      "transport": "car"
    },
    {
      "departure": "London",
      "arrival": "Amsterdam",
      "cost": 120,
      "transport": "bus"
    }
  ]
};

const min = data.deals
  .filter(d => d.departure == "London" && d.arrival == "Amsterdam")
  .reduce((agg, d) => Math.min(agg, d.cost), Infinity);

console.log(min);
```

Comment: filter, reduce  etc. are properties of map?

Comment: they are methods of arrays

Comment: Now can i access the "transport" of that cost also like this-
const transp= data.deals
  .filter(d => d.departure == "London" && d.arrival == "Amsterdam" && d.cost=="min")
  .reduce((d)=>d.transport);
??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#reduce`.

```js
const o={currency:"EUR",deals:[{departure:"London",arrival:"Amsterdam",cost:160,transport:"train"},{departure:"London",arrival:"Amsterdam",cost:40,transport:"car"},{departure:"London",arrival:"Amsterdam",cost:120,transport:"bus"}]};
const res = o.deals.reduce((acc, curr) => 
   curr.departure === "London" && curr.arrival === "Amsterdam" ? 
      Math.min(acc, curr.cost) 
      : acc, Infinity);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Typo: `cost` should be `acc`

Comment: @TJ Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

The `deals` key's value is an array, so you can sort it.

```js
const arr = [{"departure":"London", "arrival":"Amsterdam", "cost":160,"transport":"train"},
{"departure":"London", "arrival":"Amsterdam", "cost":40,"transport":"car"},
{"departure":"London", "arrival":"Amsterdam", "cost":120,"transport":"bus"}]

const filteredArr = arr.filter(a => a.departure === "London" && a.arrival === "Amsterdam")
function orderByCost(a, b) {
    return a["cost"] - b["cost"]
}

filteredArr.sort(orderByCost)

console.log(filteredArr)
```

and now if you want the object of the minimum cost transport, you can get the first element of the array

Comment: that's true, but this doesn't filter by arrival and departure

Comment: correct, i thought it's all about "Amsterdam" and "London" data, just adjusted :)